# contour of circle is connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am having such a hard time trying to see whether the contour of the circle is connected: $A = \{ x^2 + y^2 = 1 \} $ I mean it is intuitively obvious, but I don't know how to prove it. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Typically one uses a basic result of point set topology that the continuous image of a connected set is connected, but you can prove this directly if you wish.

Comment: How can you show circle is connected using this fact?

Comment: $f: [0,1] \to A$ defined as $f(t)=e^{2 \pi i t}$ is a continuous function, and $[0,1]$ is connected, so, its image, which is $A$, is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know [the following "main" result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Theorems), then you can apply the mapping that Twink describes to conclude the circle is connected:

**Prop.** If $\mathscr{S}$ is a connected topological space, and $f:\mathscr{S} \rightarrow \mathscr{T}$ is a continuous surjection, then $\mathscr{T}$ is also a connected topological space.

Specifically, we map $\mathbb{R}$ (which is connected) onto the circle by $f(\theta)=(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$, and the continuity of this surjection establishes (by the above proposition) that the circle is connected.